# retrieve date in format js

Tags: javascript, php

I have code like that :

```
if(substr($field, -7)=="StartDate"){ 
    // If change start date
    $end = str_replace('StartDate', 'EndDate', $field);
    if (property_exists($this, $end)) {
        echo "if(!this.value) {";
            echo "  var end = dijit.byId('$end').get('value');"; // $end will be replaced by value as enclosed by "
            echo " if(end){";
                echo "  var dtStart = $this.value;"; // => I need to retrive the date of $this in format js
                echo "  end.constraints.min=dtSatrt;";
            echo " }";
        echo "}";
    }
}
```

For the line `echo "  var dtStart = $this.value;"; // => I need to retrive the date of $this in format js` can you help me ? Thanks !!

Comment: You have to echo $this['value'] or if object $this->value through php in java script. Because I have not seen any variable or object with name in $this in java script.

Answer (score 0):

just echo  tags around the function and when it is outputted in html the script will run.

```
echo"<script>var dtStart = " . $this.value . "</script>";
```

Comment: you will probably need to adjust the formatting of the output btw.

Comment: Hello . Yes but like that i don't retrive date in format js :(

Comment: can you give me a sample output so I know what your working with>

Comment: you'll need to format $this.value before it's echoed into the js code.